# Multiple sets of duplicate records from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

How to get all the existing duplicated sets of records(based on a column) from a dataframe?

I got a dataframe as follows:

```
flight_id | from_location  | to_location |  schedule |  
1         |   Vancouver    |   Toronto   |   3-Jan   |  
2         |   Amsterdam    |   Tokyo     |   15-Feb  |  
4         |   Fairbanks    |   Glasgow   |   12-Jan  |  
9         |   Halmstad     |   Athens    |   21-Jan  |  
3         |   Brisbane     |   Lisbon    |   4-Feb   |  
4         | Johannesburg   |   Venice    |   23-Jan  |
9         | LosAngeles     |  Perth      |   3-Mar   |
```

Here flight_id is the column on which I need to check duplicates. And there are 2 sets of duplicates.

Output for this specific example should look like--`[(2,5),(3,6)]`. List of tuples of record index values

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you need ? `duplicated`+`groupby`

```
(df.loc[df['flight_id'].duplicated(keep=False)].reset_index()).groupby('flight_id')['index'].apply(tuple)
Out[510]: 
flight_id
4    (2, 5)
9    (3, 6)
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Adding `tolist` at the end

```
(df.loc[df['flight_id'].duplicated(keep=False)].reset_index()).groupby('flight_id')['index'].apply(tuple).tolist()
Out[511]: [(2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

And another solution ... for fun only

```
s=df['flight_id'].value_counts()
list(map(lambda x : tuple(df[df['flight_id']==x].index.tolist()), s[s.gt(1)].index))
Out[519]: [(2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `apply` and a `lambda`

```
df.groupby('flight_id').apply(
    lambda d: tuple(d.index) if len(d.index) > 1 else None
).dropna()

flight_id
4    (2, 5)
9    (3, 6)
dtype: object
```

---

Or better with an iteration through the `groupby` object

```
{k: tuple(d.index) for k, d in df.groupby('flight_id') if len(d) > 1}

{4: (2, 5), 9: (3, 6)}
```

---

Just the tuples

```
[tuple(d.index) for k, d in df.groupby('flight_id') if len(d) > 1]

[(2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

---

**Leaving this for posterity**
*But I now highly dislike this approach.  It's just too gross.*
I was messing around with `itertools.groupby`
Others may find this fun

```
from itertools import groupby

key = df.flight_id.get
s = sorted(df.index, key=key)
dict(filter(
    lambda t: len(t[1]) > 1,
    ((k, tuple(g)) for k, g in groupby(s, key))
))

{4: (2, 5), 9: (3, 6)}
```

Comment: I like your thinking.  You always seem to optimize the solution in your head before coding.  +1  I enjoy your answer so much.

Comment: @ScottBoston too kind.  Thank you.

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree with @ScottBoston.

Comment: Agree haha  @ScottBoston

Comment: Wow, that second option is a monstrosity :D

Answer (score 6):

Performing a `groupby` on `df.index` can take you places.

```
v = df.index.to_series().groupby(df.flight_id).apply(pd.Series.tolist)
v[v.str.len().gt(1)]

flight_id
4    [2, 5]
9    [3, 6]
dtype: object
```

You can also get cute with *just* `groupby` on `df.index` directly.

```
v = pd.Series(df.index.groupby(df.flight_id))
v[v.str.len().gt(1)].to_dict()

{
    "4": [
        2,
        5
    ],
    "9": [
        3,
        6
    ]
}
```